# Dark Souls PTDE: How do I completely clear cache

Tags: dark-souls

For Dark Souls PTDE, I want to completely clean my cache with my saves still intact (are they saved via the Cloud?). Is there a way I can do that, since I crash when launching the game and it's probably from a mod?

Comment: Do you have or did you have DSFix installed and/or are you running the steamworks beta version?

Comment: @slow_excellence I had DSFix and probably a few others. The settings would crash me for some reason. Is there a way to stop crashing with things like Anti-Aliasing enabled?

Comment: You absolutely need to have AA disabled. If you can't launch the game, delete all of the residual DSFix files. Otherwise you should be able to disable AA if you can make it to the menu. If you're going to install DSFix, you need to download v2.4 since that has the proper entries for the steamworks version of dark souls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to replace the DSFix to highlight the files, then remove them. I had to reset my game options but then it worked fine.